# How to find urls and image for any given entity?

Tags: web-crawler, data-mining

I am working on some web mining stuff, and trying to find web urls (for example, wikipedia page and home page ) of some particular entity. By entity I mean some player name, location etc. For example if my input is David Beckham, I want following as output :

Url Results:

http://www.davidbeckham.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Beckham

and image result as :

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/WikiBex.jpg

Can someone please point out any method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posing as it might be helpful for others. Several Semantic Web implementation are quite useful in finding information about entities. I found dbpedia (which is semantic web representation of wikipedia) very useful, though there is some steep learning curve such as SPARQL, RDFs but it's worthy and exciting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fairly easy:

You only need to implement a search engine such as Google. Then you can search for the name and it will give you the results you desire!

Comment: Need not to write search engine, dbpedia spotlight could be used to solve this problem.